# Dropdown list value is not saving in database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

My dropdown list is display well but is not saving in database. I am using spring mvc to fetch list. DAO implementation:

```
@Override
    public List<Item_entity> getItemList() {
        Session session = null;
        List<Item_entity> item = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item_entity.class);
            item = criteria.list();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.flush();
            if (session != null && session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
        return item;
    }
```

In controller, I am using modelandview.addObject for jsp use.

```
mav.addObject("item", new Item_entity());
mav.addObject("itemList", this.master_service.getItemList());
```

And I am using this in jsp like this:

```
<form:select type='list' id="item_code2" path="item.item_code" class="dropdown">
        <option value='' class="select-items">Select Item Code</option>
        <c:if test="${!empty itemList}">
        <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="list">
        <form:option value="${list.item_code}" class="select-items">${list.item_code} : ${list.item_type}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

List is shown properly but value is not saving in database. Please see my problem. And give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Item_entity bean class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item_entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_code")
    private Integer item_code;

    @Column(name = "item_type")
    private String item_type;

    public Integer getItem_code() {
        return item_code;
    }

    public void setItem_code(Integer item_code) {
        this.item_code = item_code;
    }

    public String getItem_type() {
        return item_type;
    }

    public void setItem_type(String item_type) {
        this.item_type = item_type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item_entity [item_code=" + item_code + ", item_type=" + item_type + "]";
    }
```

Comment: where is your session.save() and save method for items? Kindly show that code i.e. where is your saveItemList() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by some changing in JSP code only.

```
**Just give name of field to save value in database.**

<form:select type='list' ***name="item_code2"*** id="item_code2" path="item.item_code" class="dropdown">
        <option value='' class="select-items">Select Item Code</option>
        <c:if test="${!empty itemList}">
        <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="list">
        <form:option value="${list.item_code}" class="select-items">${list.item_code} : ${list.item_type}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```